# Laravel Eloquent Sum elements after groupBy

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, sum

I am having a two-level group in Laravel and want to sum the amount for each final group.

The model is similar as:

```
Plan
=====================
id | user_id | game_id | option | amount
```

And my query is:

```
$allbets = DB::table('plan')
            ->select('plan.amount', 'plan.option', 'users.name')
            ->join('users', 'plan.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where(['plan.game_id' => $game->id])
            ->get()
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->map(function ($option) {
                return $option
                    ->groupBy('option');
            })
        ;
```

I need to summerize the "amount" of each second-level "option" group.
Actual Results are:

```
username1 =>
   option1 =>
      0 =>
          username1
          option1
          10
      1 =>
          username1
          option1
          12

username2 =>
   option1 =>
      0 =>
          username2
          option1
          10
      1 =>
          username1
          option1
          12
   option2 =>
      0 =>
          username2
          option2
          5
      1 =>
          username1
          option2
          6
```

I need this result:

```
username1 =>
   option1 =>
          22

username2 =>
   option1 =>
          22
   option2 =>
          11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the laravel `reduce()` method https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-reduce.

Inside your map function add in reduce after the group by like so:

```
->map(function ($option) {
    return $option
        ->groupBy('option')
        ->map(function($group) {
           // Loop through each group and reduce them.
           $group->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
                // Assume that we always want the last value by using php end() function on array.
                return $carry + end($item);
           }, 0);
        });

});
```

I haven't tested this so if there are issues let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Only please make these small changes:
->map(function ($option) {
    return $option
     ->groupBy('option')
     ->map(function ($group) {
      return
      $group->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
       return $carry + end($item);
      }, 0);
     });
   });

Comment: @abullock Awesome. Ah, yes that makes sense.  Updated now.